# How do I use merge sort to sort high scores out?

Tags: python, mergesort

```
def sort(data):

    if len(data) > 1:
        midpoint = int(len(data) / 2)
    left, right = sort(data[:midpoint]), sort(data[midpoint:])
    
    sort(left, right)

def sort(left, right):

    result = []
    left_pointer = right_pointer = 0
    
    while left_pointer < len(left) and right_pointer < len(right):
        result.append(left[left_pointer])
        left_pointer += 1
    
    else:
    
        result.append(right[right_pointer])
        right_pointer += 1
    
    result.extend(left[left_pointer:])
    result.extend(right[right_pointer:])
    
    return result

sort([3, 1, 2])
```

The task I need to do is the following
"The next issue with the game is the high score table: it is not sorted. This needs to be fixed. Therefore, this task is to implement a sorting algorithm of your choice into task2_sort.py. We will award marks proportional to the complexity of the algorithm you implement. Therefore, implementing Merge sort will get more marks than Bubble sort, but you are free to implement a typically even faster algorithm such as Quick sort.

The high scores consist of a list of lists of the form: [[score1, name1], [score2, name2], ... ], where score is the value you need to sort, and name is a string. Accessing the data is similar to indexing a list, but you then need to access the score of each element through indexing the zero'th element of the sub list.

For example, to access the score of the first element of data is data[0][0], and the second element of data is data[1][0].
The task stated what else do I need to do in order for this to work iv been looking online for ages but it only shows how to do it in another file"

The game launches but when you get a game over the game crashes
This is the error "line 55, in add
self.score_data = sort(self.score_data)
TypeError: sort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'"

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Comment: What means "game crashes"? If there are error messages show them completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: It almost looks like you're defining two functions named "sort". That's going to cause problems from name shadowing after you fix the more obvious errors.

Comment: I dont know what the obvious errors are iv tried looking online for a while and Im still new to this @KennyOstrom

Comment: They are obvious in that python tells you about them when you try to run it. Although now that I actually try to run it, python also complains about the two sorts, indirectly. You need to run the code on some dummy data to see if it actually sorts it, and you can fix easy problems on the way, as python tells you exactly what to fix and where with errors like "builtins.IndentationError" as one example.

Comment: I can answer now that you gave an error message. I fixed your indentation so that the code in the question actually gives that error. It is what I said in my comment yesterday, but my answer explains it in much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a variable, then you give it a new value, then the old value is gone (or at least inaccessible to you).

```
x = 5
x = 3
print(x)
```

> 3

This is also true of functions. Functions are objects, and the name "sort" can only refer to one of them.

```
def sort(data):
    print ('sort was called with one argument')
    data.sort()


def sort(left, right):
    print ('sort was called with two arguments')
    return left + right


data = [5, 1, 3, 4, 2]
sort(data)
print(data)
```

> builtins.TypeError: sort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'

If we look above, we see that python is correct. You defined sort as taking two arguments left and right. The other sort is no longer accessible as its name has been reused.

Normally mergesort would use a helper function called "merge" but you called it "sort" thus making it impossible to access the function that used to be called "sort"

I suspect you were expecting c++ polymorphism, but that's not python.

Comment: While just renaming the second sort to merge does fix this particular error, you still have some work to fix the recursion, and merge doesn't pass testing, but those are separate issues.